# Magento Invalid method Mage_Sales_Model_Order

Tags: php

I have issue in magento backend

> Sales--->Orders---->Individual orders showing error like
>
> Invalid method Mage_Sales_Model_Order::isBeingDispatched(Array ( ) )

Trace:

```
#0/app/code/community/MDN/AdvancedStock/Model/Observer.php(275): Varien_Object->__call('isBeingDispatch...', Array)
```

So iam not able to check orders in backend. It happen suddenly before it's working fine.Please help me someone to solve this.

Thanks
Mohan NK

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you figured it out but here it is:

class `MDN_AdvancedStock_Model_Sales_Order` extends `Mage_Sales_Model_Order`.

Check if the rewrite works, the method should be in `MDN_AdvancedStock_Model_Sales_Order`.

The extension is from: *boostmyshops ERP package*. I have a lot of experience with it.

Answer (score -1):

This is the support from BoostMyShop. Please contact us on the site support and we will help you with pleasure.

This error means you have an unresolved conflict on Mage_Sales_Model_Order

Please note this extends has been removed from ERP version after June 2016. (ERP 2.9.6.0)

ERP is provided with a tool called Magento extension confict that can help you to sort out these kind of issue easily : 
http://documentation.boostmyshop.com/extension_conflict/3_how_to_use.html

This tool is provided with ERP if you have a valid licence.

Best regards, 
BoostMyShop Support